# How to retrieve data from a column of db2 table which is having special characters? Can someone help me

Tags: database, db2

I have a DB2 table in which I have a column having special characters. Now I want to retrieve the data from that table having special characters.

SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE Vendor LIKE '[^A-Za-z0-9]';
I have tried executing above query but it is not giving the result.

Comment: What is a special character? What is the encoding? What is `hex(vend_prod_serl_nbr)` for one of the rows that have special characters?

Comment: What is a special character? Nowadays pretty much all drivers retrieve UTF-8 all day long, and other "full encodings" (chinese, japanese, etc.). This is a non-issue unless you are using 20-year old drivers (or you are running in an old Windows version).

Comment: Please, edit your question with your DB2 version and platform.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for DB2 for LUW is to use one of the corresponding regexp functions.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  VALUES 
    'DB2'
  , 'DB2 V11.5'
) Invoice (Vendor) 
WHERE 
-- Since DB2 v11.1
--REGEXP_LIKE (Vendor, '[^A-Za-z0-9]')

-- Since DB2 v9.7
XMLCAST (XMLQUERY ('fn:matches($s, "[^A-Za-z0-9]")' PASSING Vendor AS "s") AS INT) = 1
```

The result is:

| VENDOR |
| --- |
| DB2 V11.5 |